# How to enable ARC for a file in Non-ARC project?

Tags: iphone, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I know you can use `-fno-objc-arc` flag to disable ARC for files that NOT support ARC in an ARC project.

Is there any way to enable ARC for files support ARC in a Non-ARC project?

Thanks!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Yup: add the `-fobjc-arc` flag the same way.

Comment: But it might cause leaks in certain scenarios

Comment: @Deepukjayan could you elaborate -- what scenarios exactly?